# IPython woes - cannot reinstall

Tags: python, ipython

I was having this error message when I tried to run IPython

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
  from IPython import start_ipython
ImportError: cannot import name start_ipython
```

So I decided to do:

```
sudo pip uninstall ipython
sudo pip install ipython
```

I cannot reinstall it, I get this error msg:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

I am running Mac OS X 10.9

Comment: So your Python ecosystem is somehow screwed up. That can happen when you use different installation methods for different things. I am pretty sure that if you would always have used `pip`, you would not have this problem. What you should do now is to (unfortunately) manually clean all traces of IPython in different places, and also  remove all pip temp data.

Comment: did you use a package manager to install it also?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Unfortunately I agree with you.  When I first started using Python, I'm pretty sure I installed different versions all over the place and this seems to have been causing me troubles ever since.  Do you know if re-install OS X (not a clean install - this one http://support.apple.com/kb/ph13871) would give me a fresh Python installation?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If I did, I would have used `brew`.  Doing `brew uninstall ipython` returns `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ipython`

Comment: cd to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages, check if it is there and manually delete it, I had the same problem on ubuntu  installing with pip after installing with  apt-get previously. Be careful what you delete!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks that worked!  But I am back to my first error message when I try and start ipython `ImportError: cannot import name start_ipython`

Comment: what do you get from ` which ipython`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `/usr/local/bin/ipython`

Comment: and `which -a python`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham
which -a ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54216/discussion-between-padraic-cunningham-and-mchangun).